# Cannot change my display frequency / refresh rate on KDE + Arch

Tags: arch-linux, kde, display

It seems that my current environment (Arch Linux and KDE) is forcing me to use only the native display resolution and frequency for my laptop. My laptop is a gaming laptop, a Dell G15 with both Intel integrated graphics and an Nvidia RTX 3050m.

This is what KDE outputs:

[image: Display configuration: says "Refresh rate: 120 Hz"]

This is what `xrandr` outputs:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080    120.04*+
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I want to lower my refresh rate to 60 Hz, I even tried manually adding it to `xrandr` using the command line, but, sadly, it did not work.

What is happening here? 
It works as expected on the Windows side (I have a dual boot).

On a side note, both `nvidia-settings` and `nvidia-smi` refuse to open. 
Maybe it's a driver problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the IGPU in the bios.
If you cant use the NVIDIA services, there might be the problem that Linux uses the IGPU instead of the nvidia gpu.
I had a similar problem.

-> [Terminal freezes for every command regarding the Nvidia graphics card](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712899/terminal-freezes-for-every-command-regarding-the-nvidia-graphics-card)