# Terminal freezes for every command regarding the Nvidia graphics card

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, laptop

I have a (gaming) laptop (Dell G15) which uses an hybrid graphics setup; the main Arch Linux environment apparently uses the intel iGPU drivers, but my laptop has an RTX 3050m.

I have the nvidia drivers and other nvidia related packages installed, however, any time I try to bring up nvidia related commands on the terminal it completely hangs. Doing some googling, there was someone else here with the same problem (https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=274405&p=2) but the "solution" was not a real solution as the person had to switch laptops.

So any of the following commands results in freezing:

```
nvidia-smi
```

(works fine on Windows but not on my Arch install, on the same machine):

```
nvidia-settings
```

(does not open at all)

```
prime-run glxgears
```

(this tries to use GPU acceleration to render, freezes and nothing opens meanwhile running it without "prime-run" works and displays as expected since it's using the Intel drivers and not nvidia's)

I cannot debug it at all since it freezes without any output.

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

outputs:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

and

```
xrandr --listproviders
```

outputs:

```
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x47 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 5 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
```

So while my Nvidia card is being detected by the kernel, it is not showing up as a provider for X for some reason.

What do you suggest and what could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `optirun` instead of `prime-run`? What is the output of `optirun glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"`? Do you have a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-optimus-manager.conf` file? What does it say? Also, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA#Installation and search for `FS#74886`, there's a bug that means the nvidia module can't be loaded, and you need to add `ibt=off` to grub.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out [@terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon)

This problem happens on Linux Kernel 5.18 when you have an Nvidia card and an Intel CPU.

I managed to fix it by using the following steps:

```
sudo nano /et/default/grub
```

Then changing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to also include **ibt=off** among the parameters.

Then I saved, and executed:

```
sudo update-grub
reboot
```

Then the laptop should detect the Nvidia card just fine.